# Ubuntu 20.10 boots to black screen on Asus laptop

Tags: boot, xubuntu

My laptop doesn't boot anymore in the normal boot mode. After GRUB, it reaches a black screen and responds to nothing (not even Ctrl+Alt+F1 for terminal access). It works fine in recovery mode.

Following some threads on StackExchange I tried to boot by editing the boot options and replacing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` but that doesn't change anything to the problem.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

```
XUbuntu 20.10 groovy

# lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 515 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)
```

In case this is relevant I run a dual boot with Windows. I've also already tried to reinstall Ubuntu. Strangely enough I think when I freshly installed it worked well for a few boots but then the problem came back (?).

Comment: Have you taken a note of a boot time and an exact time it seems to hang, then boot to recovery mode and looked at logs such as `/var/log/syslog` to see if there are any clues between startup time and hang time?

Comment: after GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1", did you call "sudo update-grub" because i experienced that has not worked without updating grub.

Comment: @inspiron, I didn't use grub-update but rather edited the boot commands directly in grub (by pressing the 'e' key if that makes sense). Now I've also tried your suggestion, both changing that line and then running update-grub, but still the same problem persists. Thanks for the idea though!

Comment: @codlord thanks, that sounds like a great idea. I have no idea how I can find the exact time it seems to hang, because immediately following grub all I see is a black screen. Do you have an idea how I can find that information?